# ember qunit needs unknown controller factory

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js, qunit

I have this test for a controller; it is using `ember-flash-message` controller:

```
moduleFor 'controller:about', 'About Controller', {
    needs: ['controller:flashMessage']
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Setup failed on exists: Attempting to register an
 unknown factory: `controller:flashMessage`
```

I am sure I included the FlashMessageController. Why do I get this error?

Comment: I'm seeing it as working using a basic example, http://jsbin.com/qawak/1/edit .  Can you try consoling out App.FlashMessageController right before the `moduleFor`

Comment: @Kingpin2k Oh, now i see, flash-message-controller is defined as `Ember.FlashMessageController`, [see this line](https://github.com/ryanto/ember-flash-message/blob/master/flash-message.js#L1), but `App.FlashMessageController` is `undefined` in my case, what should i do, and how did you get it working?

Comment: Is there a reason you defined those on the Ember namespace instead of your app's namespace?  You could just add a reference to your namespace for the controller and that would work as well.

Comment: @Kingpin2k well it's a plugin i didn't write it, how do we use plugins in ember? Is this OK `App.FlashMessageController = Ember.FlashMessageController`?

Comment: Ahhh, I see, yeah, you could totally do that, even if you just did it right before the test for the tests purpose